# Reversing the contents of an std::list

Tags: c++, list, stl, iostream, reverse

```
class Print 
   {  
   public:
       void PrintAll() {}
   private:
    std::list<int> mylist;
   };
```

I see this example question from a C++ language book.
And I want to print the internal mylist elements.
How can it be done if mylist needs to be reversed, using C++ STL library and using  to output the result.

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Please add the code for PrintAll( )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`std::list<>::reverse()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/reverse)?

That said, if you only need to *print* the `list` in reverse, you can simply print it using `list`'s reverse iterators (obtained by [`std::list<>::rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin) and [`std::list<>::rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rend)) rather than by using `list`'s normal iterators. E.g.:

```
// given std::list<int> l;
for (std::list<int>::const_reverse_iterator iter(l.rbegin()), iter_end(l.rend());
        iter != iter_end;
        ++iter)
{
    std::cout << *iter << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `std::copy( l.rbegin(), l.rend(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) );`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `reverse()` method on your list.

```
mylist.reverse();
```

will reverse the contents of your list and then you can print the same, using iterators.

```
list<int>::iterator it;
cout << "mylist contains:";
for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;
```

You can wrap all the functionality up in your own member function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use reverse iterators provided by the container e.g. l.rbegin() and l.rend() and that will iterate through the list backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Code example for **list::reverse**

```
// list_reverse.cpp
// compile with: /EHsc
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main( ) 
{
   using namespace std;
   list <int> c1;
   list <int>::iterator c1_Iter;

   c1.push_back( 10 );
   c1.push_back( 20 );
   c1.push_back( 30 );

   cout << "c1 =";
   for ( c1_Iter = c1.begin( ); c1_Iter != c1.end( ); c1_Iter++ )
      cout << " " << *c1_Iter;
   cout << endl;

   c1.reverse( );
   cout << "Reversed c1 =";
   for ( c1_Iter = c1.begin( ); c1_Iter != c1.end( ); c1_Iter++ )
      cout << " " << *c1_Iter;
   cout << endl;
}
```

And the output will be

**c1 = 10 20 30
Reversed c1 = 30 20 10**

Answer (score 0):

iterator simply point to the current element in the list. So, if we write a for loop going from end to beginning, we can print the list in reverse. in the code given below:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       std::list<int> ii;
       ii.push_back(1);
       ii.push_back(2);
       ii.push_back(3);
       ii.push_back(4);
       ii.push_back(5);
       for (std::list<int>::iterator it = (ii.begin()); it != (ii.end()) ; ++it)
       {
           cout << (*it) << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
       for (std::list<int>::iterator it = (--ii.end()); it != (--ii.begin()) ; it--)
       {
           cout << (*it) << " ";
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

The first for loop prints out the list from front to back while the second one prints from back to front.